# What distribution could the data stem from?

Tags: poisson-distribution, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, exponential-distribution, distribution-identification

From checking the histogram of the distribution I had the intuition that the data could follow a Poisson or an exponential distribtuion.

[image]

However, Lilliefors test that the data is exponentially distributed can be rejected

```
lilliefors(log_filesImportedMining['files_imported'], dist='exp', pvalmethod='table')
(0.35391091160912636, 0.0009999999999998899)
```

The same goes for the  Kolmogorov-Smirnov (K-S) test, which strangely gives a p-value of literally 0.0.

```
kstest(list(log_filesImportedPredictive['files_imported']), 'poisson', args=(log_filesImportedPredictive.mean()))
KstestResult(statistic=0.34115413210541, pvalue=0.0)
```

.

**Questions:**

1. Could it be that I made a mistake with the kstest, since the p-value is 0.0?
2. Any other ideas what kind of distribution this could be?
3. Any other methods to test?

Thanks.

Comment: What does this variable represent in the real world? Is it a count?

Comment: Why do you care? Raw data are rarely found to arise from a simple probability distribution. Do you have reason to think that this data should ? Where does the data come from ? More often we are interested in a conditional distribution.

Comment: If I understand your display correctly a Poisson distribution is ruled out absolutely as your data aren't counts. An exponential is implausible. The key point is that made by @Robert Long: although introductory texts or courses sometimes like to imply otherwise, real data often do not fit named distributions well and that doesn't much matter.

Comment: P-values reported as 0 usually just mean too small to print.

Comment: @kjetil-b-halvorsen & robert-long it represents the amount of files imported inside a notebook. Yes, it is count data. Unfortunately, I cannot give more information than that. Having said that, how should I proceed?

Comment: That zeros does not occur (as can be seen from the histogram) means that Poisson does not apply, it would have to be truncated Poisson. Can you show the mean and variance? Maybe consider (truncated) negative binomial as an alternative to (trucated) Poisson?

Comment: @kjetil-b-halvorsen  I forgot to mention that the data underwent a logarithmic transformation. Furthermore, the least amount of datasets imported that there can be is equal to two. Is there a test for truncated Poisson?

Comment: here the stats you requested @kjetil-b-halvorsen : mean = 1.58 std= 0.72

Comment: That could even mean *underdispersion* relative to a (truncated) Poisson model, which is not very common. Could there be dependencies in the data, some groups structure underlying the data? Try to fit a truncated Poisson and show us the result: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55639/what-is-the-difference-between-a-zero-inflated-and-a-zero-truncated-poisson

Comment: @kjetil-b-halvorsen I'm not really a statistician, so I'm having a hard time with some of the concepts you mentioned. Are there any simple tests with Python that I could use for this?

Comment: I don't know python, so not ... anyhow, you think to much in terms of tests. You need first to describe the data. Maybe take a step back, and tell us more about how you did obtain the data (random sample? groups? other dependencies? ... and most importantly, what is your goal? Maybe you don't even needvto fit a distribution!

Comment: @kjetil-b-halvorsen the data was filtered to contain notebooks that import more than two datasets. I have to show from which distribution the data could stem from for my master thesis. My guess was Poisson or Exponential, but it seems that I'm wrong.

Comment: Please add this new information as an edit to the post. And, can you share (a link to) the data?